# Cocoa Distributed Objects, Long Polling, launchd and "Not Responding" in Activity Monitor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc, launchd, distributed-objects

Scenario:

I have a Distributed-objects-based IPC between a mac application and a launchd daemon (written with Foundation classes). Since I had issues before regarding asynchronous messaging (e.g. I have a registerClient: on the server's root object and whenever there's an event the server's root object notifies / calls a method in the client's proxy object), I did long-polling which meant that the client "harvests" lists of events / notifications from the daemon. This "harvest" is done through a server object method call, which then returns an NSArray instance.

It works pretty well, until for a few seconds, the server object's process (launched thru launchd) starts being labeled red with the "(Not responding)" tag beside it (inside Activity Monitor). Like I said, functionally, it works well, but we just want to get rid of this "Not responding" label.

**How can I prevent this "Not responding" tag?**

FYI, I already did launchd-based processes before and this is the first time I did long-polling. Also, I tried NSSocketPortNameServer-based connections and also NSSocketPort-based ones. They didn't have this problem. Locking wasn't also an issue 'coz the locks used were only NSCondition's and we logged and debugged the program and it seems like the only locking "issue" is on the harvesting part, which actually, functionally works. Also, client-process is written in PyObjC while server process was written using ObjC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for best typo ever!  I love the "lunch daemon!!"

Comment: Haha. Sorry about that. Anyway, I changed it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was actually the call for getting a process's PID using the signature `FNDR`... that part caused the "Not responding" error and it never was the locks or the long-polling part. Sorry about this guys. But thank God I already found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Sample](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html) the process to find out what it's doing or waiting on.

Answer (score 2):

Peter's correct in the approach, though you may be able to figure it out through simple inspection. "Not responding" means that you're not processing events on your event queue for at least 5 seconds (used to be 2 seconds, but they upped it in 10.4). For a UI process, this would create a spinning wait cursor, but for a non-UI process, you're not seeing the effects as easily.

If this is a runloop-based program, it means you're probably doing something with a blocking (synchronous) operation that should be done with the run loop and a callback (async). Alternately, you need a second thread to process your blocking operations so your mainthread can continue to respond to events.

Comment: That's a handful of information there. I'll check on my code later. Thanks a lot :)